# Arduino - sending large amount of data over Serial

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I am trying to build a simple FLASH memory programmer (for 39SF020A) using my arduino mega. I wrote the C code and Python script to send the data over (And it all works as expected). 
I need to transfer about 32k of hexadecimal data, but with my settings only 10k of data took about 4 minutes (115200 BAUD), which i found unnecessary long. Currently, i am sending over serial (from Python) my value with a terminator (i chose '$'), so for exmple '3F$'. adresses are calulated on the arduino, so no need to send them.

In my arduino code, i have

`String received_string = Serial.readStringUntil('$');`

and after programming every byte to teh FLASH using arduino, it sends back a '\n' to let the Python know, that it is ready to receive next byte (the python is waiting for receiving a 'line' and then continues). I am not really sure if this is a way to do it, if sending only one byte at the time is good idea and if not, how many and how do i parse them on the arduino? Is the feedback loop useful?

Thanks.

Python Code:
('file' contains all data)

```
for item in file[1:]:
ser.write((item + "$").encode("ascii"))
line = ser.readline()
i += 1

if i >= top:
    break
elif (i % 100) == 0:
    print(i)
```

Arduino code (just part of it)

```
if (Serial.available() > 0){
    String received_string = Serial.readStringUntil('$');
    programData(received_string.toInt(),program_adress);
    program_adress++;
}
void programData(char data_in, unsigned long adress)
{
  digitalWrite(OE,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CE,LOW);
  writeByte(0xAA, 0x5555);
  writeByte(0x55, 0x2AAA);
  writeByte(0xA0, 0x5555);
  writeByte(data_in, adress);
  Serial.print("\n");    // Feedback for Python
  delayMicroseconds(30); // Just to be on the safe side
}


void writeByte(char data_in, unsigned long adress)
{
  setDataAs(OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(OE,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(WE,HIGH);
  setAdress(adress);
  setData(data_in);
  digitalWrite(WE,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  digitalWrite(WE,HIGH);
}


// Sets data BUS to input or output
void setDataAs(char dir){
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data_size    ;i++) pinMode(data[i],dir); 
}

// Sets data to specific values
void setData(char data_i){
  setDataAs(OUTPUT);
  for (int i = 0; i < data_size;i++) { digitalWrite(data[i],bitRead(data_i,i)); }
}



void setAdress(long adr){
// Set all adresses
for (int i = 0; i < adresses_size;i++)    
   digitalWrite(adresses[i],bitRead(adr,i));
}
```

Comment: please don't write 1 page and explain what your code does. just post your code with some comments. that's far more useful.

Comment: For each byte of data you transmit 3 byte to the arduino and 1 byte back. This makes about 30 sec for 10kB of data, if I calculate properly. If it takes 8 times longer in reality, the main problem must be somewhere else. Can't be your silly (and wrong) String.toInt detour ( What's the result of `String("3F").toInt();` ?)

Comment: @datafiddler yeah, but somehow the data in the flash memory was correct. I have included other part of the code, firstly, i thought the lag would be somewhere in transfer...   so i have some awful loops in there, lets see if i can optimize it

Comment: @datafiddler thx for your comment, I'm tired, I read milliseconds instead of microseconds ;)

Comment: @Piglet ;=) bad luck for Kralik_011, an answer is gone (for the moment). Perhaps he should arrange the secret `data[data_size]` bits into atmega ports and address them directly instead of using pinMode and digitalWrite so heavily. I hoped you had a feeling how much this sums up.

Comment: @datafiddler Sure. Thanks

Comment: You're not clear as what the data format is.  If you're not using something like Intel hex or Motorola S formats, then how are you validating the data that is received?